# Creating a dictionary from a 3 element tuple in Python - TypeError

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, typeerror

I'm trying to create a dictionary out of file that has a list of students in the following form:
first name   last name   points
The idea behind the dictionary is that it shows the student name with the student's points. I have converted the file input into a 3 element tuple but I get an error message when trying to convert it into a dictionary: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
Here's my code:

```
s = open(sfile, "rt")
# create dictionary
rating = {}
#create working lists
students = []
points = []
#read file and get rid of white spaces
cont = s.read()
students = cont.split("\n")
for i in students:
    points += i.split("\t")
# get students as tuples
students = list(zip(points[::3], points[1::3], points[2::3]))
#convert tuples into dictionary
rating = {{fn: ln}: pnt for fn, ln, pnt in students}
```

Comment: Please post sample input as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line of code

> rating = {{fn: ln}: pnt for fn, ln, pnt in students}

You are trying to use a dictionary **{fn: ln}** as a key of the other dictionary. Which is not possible as far as I know. That's the reason you got an error like this.

> dictionary: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Just to add ... maybe you wanted to have something like this: `rating = {fn+ln: pnt for fn, ln, pnt in students}`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use a dict as a key to another dict, this is not possible since dict are mutable.
Not sure of what you're looking for since i have no data, but maybe this could help:

```
students_fn = ['John', 'Sansa', 'Aria']
students_ln = ['Targaryen', 'Stark', 'WhoKnows']
points = [7,8,99]

rating = {ln+' '+fn: point for ln, fn, point in zip(students_ln, students_fn, points)}
```

{'Targaryen John': 7, 'Stark Sansa': 8, 'WhoKnows Aria': 99}